# Copy file from Elastic beanstalk to local machine

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have connected to Elastic Beanstalk using:

> eb ssh XXXXXX --profile=xx

Now I want to copy a file to my local machine, how do I do that?

Answer (score 39):

To figure out what IP address and keyfile to use with `scp`, you can run 
`eb ssh my-env-name` and pay attention to the first few lines of output:

```
  INFO: SSH port 22 open.
  INFO: Running ssh -i /Users/MyHome/.ssh/eb.pem ec2-user@<eb-env-ip-address>
```

Then, we can use these details for the actual `scp` command (replacing `ssh` with `scp` and adding file paths):

```
  scp -i /Users/MyHome/.ssh/eb.pem ec2-user@<eb-env-ip-address>:/path/to/file .
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use regular scp command.

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/beanstalk-env-key.pem ec2-user@beanstalk.host.ip:/path/to/file.txt ./file.txt
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you will have to open port 22 in your elastic beanstalk security group, if it is not already open. The `eb ssh` command does this automatically for you, but running `scp` from the command line will not.

Comment: An easy way to do that might just be to `eb ssh` into the machine with a second console.

Comment: Use `-r` switch to copy sub-folders recursively.
`scp -r -i ~/.ssh/beanstalk-env-key.pem ec2-user@beanstalk.host.ip:/path/to/file.txt ./file.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I think [pscl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307972/copy-file-from-elastic-beanstalk-to-local-machine/49216376#49216376) is the best one. Its very easy and is only 2 steps.

But, if you wanted to script it and maybe have only a single step, you could build on [Michal's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40983938/102616).

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/yourkey.pem ~/localfile ec2-user@`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:elasticbeanstalk:environment-name,Values=ENVIRONMENT_NAME" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress' --output text`:~/
```

You could write an alias pretty easily. The next step would be working out how to dynamically swap in the environment name based on current branch.

Comment: pscl's answer does not tell us how to get the actual file. It merely tells us how to figure out what IP address and keyfile to use.

Comment: Yes my answer is to be used in conjunction with the `scp` command in Alex_hha's answer below. But Christian's answer is clever if you need to do it on a regular basis.

Comment: I edited @pscl's answer to include the `scp` part. Maybe the edit will be accepted.

Comment: Best to add a fresh answer rather than change other people's answers.