# obtain public DNS from one of the Elastic Beanstalk instances from the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We like to connect directly to one of our instances of Elastic Beanstalk, thus we need to know its `public IP address`.

We normally get the `public IP` of the instance from the EC2 tab in the aws.console website. This is cumbersome because we need web browsing a couple of pages...

We have configured the `eb` utility from one of our servers, so we can poll our environments with `eb list`, or check the status with `eb status`.

How can we user the `eb` utility to obtain the public DNS of an instance of an environment?

Or is there any other way to obtain this information?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a user of EB CLI. However you could achieve what you want with 1 command using `awscli`.

First install and configure `awscli`:

```
$ pip install awscli
$ aws configure
```

**ElasticBeanstalk automatically tags EC2 instances** that are part of ElasticBeanstalk environment with `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` tag. Using this information you could filter out all your running instances that have a certain `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` tag value.

`$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:elasticbeanstalk:environment-name,Values=your-environment-name"`

Above command will give you quite a long JSON output. You could simply find `"PublicIpAddress"` in it, however you could filter this information with a tool like `jq`. So final command would look something like:

`$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:elasticbeanstalk:environment-name,Values=your-environment-name" | jq '.Reservations | .[] | .Instances | .[] | .PublicIpAddress'`

Try it.

Here is more information about various options for `awscli` command used:
[aws ec2 describe-instances docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)

**UPDATE 2017-03-12**

`jq` is unnecessary, Linux command line tools are unnecessary too. `awscli` supports `--query` option which can be used to query certain values you're interested in using [JMESPath (JSON query language)](http://jmespath.org/). In this case you would do:

`$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:elasticbeanstalk:environment-name,Values=your-environment-name" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress' --output text`

Above will print plain IP addresses, one per line.

Comment: Ubuntu asks me to install the `jq`utility. However, I posted an answer to my dilemma which doesn't require this. Im giving you an upvote because `describe-instances` was the way to go, though I used `ec2-describe-instances` which is maybe an outdated API...

Comment: You could just grep/awk/perl instead of using `jq` as well :)  it's quite a convenient tool to work with JSON compared to standard toolkit.

Comment: @arod See updated answer for a really clean syntax without external tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty way:

ec2-describe-instances $(eb status -v | grep InService | cut -d":" -f1 | awk '{print $1}') | grep INSTANCE | awk '{print $4}'